# toggling a button with another while keeping its onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

```
        <audio id='audio-player' controls='controls'>
            <source src='sound.wav' type='audio/wav'>
            Your browser does not support the audio element,
        </audio>

        <button id='play' onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').play(); document.getElementById('play').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('pause').style.display='block';">Play</button>
        <button id='pause' style='display: none' onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementsById('pause').style.display='none'; document.getElementsById('play').style.display='block';">Pause</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime -= 10;">Rewind</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime = 0;">Stop</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime += 10;">Forward</button>

        <br>
```

the expected response should be that clicking play gets rid of play and shows pause and vice versa (besides this the buttons themselves act as expected)

```
<script>
            function playPause() {
                        if (document.getElementById('play')) {
                            if (document.getElementById('play').style.display == 'none') {
                                document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'block';
                                document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'none';
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'none';
                                document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                        }
            }
        </script>

        <audio id='audio-player' controls='controls'>
            <source src='sound.wav' type='audio/wav'>
            Your browser does not support the audio element,
        </audio>

        <div id="play"><button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').play(); playPause();">Play</button></div>
        <div id="pause" style='display: none'><button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); playPause();">Pause</button></div>

        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime -= 10;">Rewind</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime = 0;">Stop</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime += 10;">Forward</button>

        <br>
```

well i got it working with a bit of a different approach to the scenario.

putting the buttons in divs.

Comment: `document.getElementsById` is not a function. Change it to `document.getElementById`. Did you even try to observe your console for such errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
            function playPause() {
                        if (document.getElementById('play')) {
                            if (document.getElementById('play').style.display == 'none') {
                                document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'block';
                                document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'none';
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById('play').style.display = 'none';
                                document.getElementById('pause').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                        }
            }
        </script>

        <audio id='audio-player' controls='controls'>
            <source src='sound.wav' type='audio/wav'>
            Your browser does not support the audio element,
        </audio>

        <div id="play"><button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').play(); playPause();">Play</button></div>
        <div id="pause" style='display: none'><button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); playPause();">Pause</button></div>

        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime -= 10;">Rewind</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime = 0;">Stop</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('audio-player').pause(); document.getElementById('audio-player').currentTime += 10;">Forward</button>

        <br>
```

well i got it working with a bit of a different approach to the scenario.

putting the buttons in divs.

its not a correct answer according to the question but it is a "correct" answer as to what i was trying to accomplish.